# Format particular column content style when exporting to PDF using DataTables

Tags: jquery, css, datatables, pdf-generation, pdfmake

I'm using [Datatables](https://datatables.net) on my site and I'm trying to make the contents of a particular column bold only when exported to PDF. I understand that simple text based formatting can be done [using this method](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/outputFormat-function.html) where export options are specified,

```
exportOptions: {
        format: {
            body: function ( data, row, column, node ) {
                // Strip $ from salary column to make it numeric
                return column === 5 ?
                    data.replace( /[$,]/g, '' ) :
                    data;
            }
        }
    }
```

But I don't understand how the output can be styled to be made bold. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

First dump your datatable content in a JSON format. You can format content of any cell of the table.

Taken from PDFMake.org documentation

```
var docDefinition = {
  content: [
    {
       table: {
        // headers are automatically repeated if the table spans over multiple pages
        // you can declare how many rows should be treated as headers
        headerRows: 1,
        widths: [ '*', 'auto', 100, '*' ],

        body: [
          [ 'First', 'Second', 'Third', 'The last one' ],
          [ 'Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value 3', 'Value 4' ],
          [ { text: 'Bold value', bold: true }, 'Val 2', 'Val 3', 'Val 4' ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
};

pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).print()
```